# How to scale ViewGroup and its child views with good performance

Tags: android

I am implementing stuff like **YouTube** App which you can drag the video window to the lower right corner.
I am able to achieve the same effect using **setLayoutParam()**, but it turns out not as fast as I expected (as smooth as YouTube).
So I use **setScaleX** and **setScaleY** instead. It's fast and the behavior is similar to **YouTube** app. But the scale seems not applied to the child views.
So, what can I do to efficiently scale a ViewGroup and it's child views. Thanks.

**layout.xml:**

```
<ScalableRelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parent" >
     <VideoView android:id="@+id/video"/>
</ScalableRelativeLayout>
```

When the **parent** get scaled, the **video** seems not scaled and only shows part of it. I guess the parent scale didn't pass to its children, so I override below method.

**Override method:**

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();      
    canvas.scale(mScale, mScale);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);     
    canvas.restore();
}
```

ScalableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout and override above method. Now the **video** scale inside **parent**, only occupy upper-left area.
It seems the video content will not affected by the view.

Comment: override its dispatchDraw()

Comment: I've tried this. But nothing happened to the **VideoView**.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. I've edited my question.

Comment: were you able to find an answer ?